# Can I define (override) a class using a style attribute?

Tags: html, css, class, styles

I'm working in a content management system that allows me limited (no) access to the stylesheets, but does allow me to insert CSS into certain templates.   So I have this:

```
<div class="inside_widget"> 
  <div class="input"><span class="form_label">Form stuff</span></div>
  <div class="input"><span class="form_label">Form stuff</span></div>
  <div class="input"><span class="form_label">Form stuff</span></div>
  etc... 
</div>
```

Where inside_widget, input, and form_label are all defined in a sheet I can't touch.   I want to put some custom CSS on "form_label" without having to touch every single span.

I tried using the style attribute in the containing div, but that did not work.

```
<div class="inside_widget" style=".form_label {color:#FFFFFF;}" >
```

Note: I want to retain everything else in the inside_widget styling, and not have to define a whole new class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what the OP is trying to achieve is not having to repeat the `style=""` attribute for every single `<span>` in his form.

This can be done by simply adding your own class name to the enclosing div's classes:

```
<div class="inside_widget myclass" ...>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Then make your own secondary stylesheet and define `myclass`:

```
.myclass span
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

You can put this secondary CSS either in a `<style>` tag in the HTML itself, or in its own CSS file linked in.

Comment: Thank you, this is simple and effective.  You're right that I was trying to avoid hitting every form element. Your solution accomplished this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this below.

```
<span class="form_label" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Form Stuff</span>
```

Inline styles like this will overwrite any css rules in a stylesheet, unless in the stylesheet they have a rule with !important

Comment: That would work, but require me to hunt down every single instance of form_label which can get hairy. I was trying to redefine form_label once.

Answer (score 0):

you do not know css right? will look like

```
<div class="inside_widget" style="color:#FFFFFF;" >
```

but I suggest you create a new css file and add whatever you want in the same

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it makes everything in inside_widget into #FFFFFF when I only want to apply that to a certain subclass and not wipe out the rest of inside_widget.